# ActionScript 3: Unexpected behaviour of array, when pushing an element

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am a bit confused by one expression:

```
var nodes:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int = 0; i<=3; i++)
{
   var node:Node = new Node(i)
   nodes.push(node);
}
trace(nodes[0].id + ":" + nodes[1].id);
```

Returned me `0:0` instead of `0:1` as I expected.

```
public class Node
{
   public var id:int;
   public function Node(id:int)
   {
      id = id
   }
}
```

How this can be explained?

Comment: All answers given are absolutely correct, it's a very common error. I do it all the time, there really should be a compiler warning for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the *argument* called `id` equal to itself, which is clearly not the intended behavior.

When there are instance variables that have the same names as arguments, you need to be explicit about *which* variable you wish to set:

```
public function Node(id:int) {
   this.id = id;
}
```

This would work too:

```
public function Node(an_id:int) {
   id = an_id; //here it implicitly assigns the instance variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, but very very hard to spot when you are in the middle of it: The constructor in your node class needs to look like this instead:

```
public function Node(id:int)
{
    this.id = id
}
```

When you omit the "this" the temporary variable id gets assigned to itself, hence the '0' in the output.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess:

```
this.id = id instead of id = id
```

You need to call your object var implicitly